# Convergence of sums of independent random variables

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, expectation

Hey I need some help with a problem:

Let $X_{n1},X_{n2},...,X_{nn}$ be independent random variables with a common distribution as follows:
$$P(X_{nk}=0)=1-\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}, P(X_{nk}=1)=\frac{1}{n}, P(X_{nk}=2)=\frac{1}{n^2}, $$

where k=1,2,.. and n=2,3,... $S_{n}=X_{n1}+X_{n2}+...+X_{nn}$, $n>=2$

Show that

$S_{n}\stackrel{d}{\rightarrow}Po(1)$ as n $\rightarrow \infty$

I've started like this:

$$E[e^{tS_{n}}]=E[e^{tX_{n1}+tX_{n2}+...+tX_{nn}}]=\prod_{k=1}^{n}E[e^{tX_{nk}}]=\prod_{n=2}^{\infty}(1-\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n}e^{t}+\frac{1}{n^2}e^{2t})$$

but I'm not sure I'm going with the right approach. Does someone have any tips for me?

Comment: Note $P(X_{nk}\in \{0,1,2\})= 2-2/n\not=1$, so we are missing some information. Also the last equality is not correct.

Comment: @Martin I noticed I recited the problem wrong, it should be $P(X_{nk}=1)=\frac{1}{n}$, I've edited that now. Do you have some suggestion where I should start over? In the last equality I take the moment generating functions and because they are independent I take them as a product, but I guess I do something wrong

Comment: Your final equations seem to have $n$ as a free variable on the left but a bound variable on the right.  Why is the right hand side not $\left(1-\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n}e^{t}+\frac{1}{n^2}e^{2t}\right)^n$?

Comment: You are presumably aiming for a limit of $e^{e^t-1}$ which is also the limit of  $\left(1+\frac1n(e^t-1)\right)^n$ as $n$ increases without limit.  This is close, if you can ignore the $-\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^2}e^{2t}$.  Can you show this is justifiable?

Comment: @Henry you're absolutley right, of course the right hand side should be a power of n. I guess all the notation made my head spin in the wrong direction. To your second question, I'll try to figure out how to show that that is justifiable